Is there a way to automate get requests in flutter using riverpod
I have a flutter application that keeps track of requests by a user and the number of requests is stored in a list. I have placed listeners on it using riverpod and the any change to be displayed on in-app icon for the screen. Is there a way for the value of the badge to update without going to the screen
 Widget _buildTopBar(String greetingMessage) {
    return Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) {
      final leaveApprovals = ref.watch(leaveApprovalsProvider);

      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 20, 0, 10),
              child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => LeaveApprovalOP(),
                          ),
                        )
                      },
                  child: Badge(
                      label: Text(leaveApprovals.length.toString()),
                      child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bell_solid,
                          color: Colors.white))),
            ),

// Provider for fetching pending leave data
final pendingLeaveProvider = FutureProvider<List<LeaveApproval>>((ref) async {
  final approvalLeave = ApprovalLeave();
  return approvalLeave.pendingLeave();
});



Can you explain more. I did not understand your prblm and what you wanted to do. Your code contains 2 provider, how are those 2 related. If you can give better explanation of prblm. I can suggest you some way to solve it.

Is there a way to use init() together with riverpod

what do you mean by init() with riverpod. Without proper explanation and code its hard to understand your prblm
